# Why custom pipe has error after filter rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I get this error:

```
Argument of type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<number>, Observable<any>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<{ x: number; y: number; }, any>'
```

on the line:

```
  this.Map.moveMap$
            .pipe(
                filter((v) => v.x !== 0 || v.y !== 0),
                this.requestTextLayerPipe(),
            )
            .subscribe();
```

Where `requestTextLayerPipe` is custom pipe:

```
private requestTextLayerPipe() {
    return pipe(
        filter((currentScale: number) => currentScale <= this.scaleLimitTextLayer.max || currentScale >= this.scaleLimitTextLayer.min),
        map(() => this.getTextLayersId()),
        filter((dispar: string[]) => dispar.length > 0),
        map((dispar: string[]) => this.getTextLayerProps(dispar)),
        switchMap((props: RequestTextLayerProps) =>
            this.Map.httpClient
                .get(this.buildUrlRequestTextLayer(props), {
                    observe: 'body',
                    responseType: 'blob',
                })
                .pipe(
                    map((response) => {
                        return { props, response };
                    }),
                    catchError((error) => of(error)),
                ),
        ),
    );
}
```

Why do I get this error and how to fit it? As I got, I should return observable in filter to `requestTextLayerPipe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because here `filter((currentScale: number)` you accept `number`, but in first block it is obvious that `{ x: number; y: number; }` is expected